# Can i push data from PC to Android over Wi-Fi

Tags: android, client-server, wifi, wireless

I want to write a program which downloads some data from Internet (PC part) and when my Android app will detect home Wi-Fi, it will request that data and PC part is send it to the phone.

How do I push data from PC to the Android over Wi-Fi? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the IP address of the computer on the local network, the best solution would probably be to write a network server that runs in the background on the PC, and the Android device would create a socket and connect to that server and exchange the necessary data.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a HTTP server on your PC, running your app as a service on Android device,
once your Android app detect the Wi-Fi, get data from the PC.